# Option clash with xcolor and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, color, incompatibility, package-options

I want to draw some coloured circles, so I loaded `tikz` in my preamble. However, now `xcolor` is telling me that it has an "option clash". How should I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

The error message is this:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 

The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [table]
Adding the global options:
  ,table
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Load `xcolor` before `tikz`:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

The problem is that `pgf/tikz` already loads `xcolor` so loading it again with a new package option triggers the error message.

Another option is to pass the table option to the class and not to the `xcolor` package. Then the packages can be loaded in any order:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

or

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo-Medina Can any options for any package be passed to the document class?

Comment: @Ariel: no, not every option for every package can be passed as a class option; it depends on how the option was declared in the package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Every option passed to the class is "global", so that it's tried with *every* loaded package. If the package knows it, it's applied; otherwise it's ignored. A package doesn't distinguish between global and local options (those which are passed in `\usepackage`). However, it's not a good idea to indiscriminately pass package options as global options. In this case it may be a good solution.

Comment: @egreg: yes, I know that; my comment was addressing cases like `\documentclass[T1]{report}
\usepackage{fontenc}` in which the option will be ignored.

Answer (score 28):

Add `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` and remove the line `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: That fixes the problem - what it is doing and why did I get this error?

Comment: @Ariel: I’m relatively sure, that it would be sufficient to load `xcolor` after the documentclass, but before other packages, that load itself (x)color. And `TikZ` is, in fact, one of those, but it loads `xcolor` without the `table` option.

Comment: Ah - so the error is because xcolor is loaded twice?

Comment: I second Ariel's query for further elucidation :-) !

Comment: this worked for me also after the '\documentclass' declaration