# How to resolve option clash for package xcolor?

Tags: color, incompatibility, package-options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Option clash with xcolor and TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz)

The following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

The document compiles fine if I just remove the `xcolor` package. If I include it (as shown in the MWE) I get the error `Option clash for package xcolor`. How should I resolve this issue? What might be the options settings that will remove the conflict?

Comment: Solved the problem by moving `xcolor` before `tikz`. Ref: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips

Comment: By commenting out your packages one by one, compiling, and checking if the error persists, I turned your "MWE" into a true _minimal_ working example. Please do this yourself before posting a question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
...
\usepackage{tikz}
```

or as an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
...

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
```