# Highlighting a row in a table

Tags: tables

I need to highlight rows 3rd and 5th in the following table. I the package `xcolor` with the optional argument `table`, but it doesn't work. And gives me an error.

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering

\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \caption{\textbf{State Table for Example 1}}
  \label{table: state table1}

\hfil % This is new 
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
x & y & X & Y \\ 
\hline
   $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\ 
   \rowcolor{blue}[0.9] 0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
   $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\ 
   \rowcolor{blue}[0.9] 1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering

\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \caption{\textbf{State Table for Example 1}}
  \label{table: state table1}


\hfil % This is new 
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
x & y & X & Y \\ 
\hline
   $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\ 
   \rowcolor{blue} 0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
   $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\ 
   \rowcolor{blue!30} 1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The second of blue rows is lighter, to show, how to obtain it.

[image]

Comment: I do it, and got this error: ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

Comment: @Maryam This error was on my example or some of its inclusion into your file? An error suggests that an option (probably `table`) is used in some other place.

Comment: @ Przemysław I copied your codes, and added that package, then got the error

Comment: @Maryam And what packages have you got in your preamble?

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. That's here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
x & y & X & Y \\ 
\hline
   $\bar{0}$  & $\bar{0}$ & 1 &1 \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{.9} 0  & 1 & 0 &1 \\ 
   $\bar{1}$  & $\bar{1}$ & 0 & 0 \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{.5} 1  & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got this error after adding the package: ! Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: I get no such error.

Comment: It found the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz