# Color Package error message

Tags: color

I am using **color** package in latex to highlight some of my text in specific red color using RGB format. my code is something like this :

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\hspace{55mm}CV $|$ \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[width=18.00cm, height=22.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{[\arabic{enumi}]}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{1.2mm}{1.2mm}
%\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\setstretch{0.01}}

%%%%%%%%%%_____________Color Text Box Packages______________%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}



%%%%%%%%%%_____________Color for Text ______________%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{139,0,0}





%%%%%%%%%%_____________Start of main document______________%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\textcolor{myred}{
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}\section{Education}}

\begin{tabular}{p{23mm}p{118mm}r}
    Undergrad&\href{http://www.buet.ac.bd/}{Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology}, Dhaka&[2013-Present]\\
    &B.Sc. in Mechanical Engineering, CGPA-3.36/4.00\vspace{1.5mm}&[February, 2017]\\
    Higher School&\href{http://www.soshgcdhaka.edu.bd/}{SOS Hermann Gmeiner College}, Dhaka&[2010-2012]\\
    &Higher Secondary Certificate (HSC), CGPA-5.00/5.00\vspace{1.5mm}&\\
    &\href{https://www.acps.edu.bd/}{Adamjee Cantonment Public School}, Dhaka&[2003-2010]\\
    &Secondary School Certificate (SSC), CGPA-5.00/5.00& 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

But when i try to compile, it shows error message and does not compile :

> Option clash for package color. \usepackage

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This is basically the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz The thing is that `tcolorbox` loads `xcolor` which loads `color`. When loading a package more than once (which you in general might as well try to avoid), the package options used the second time has to be a subset of those used the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this format of using packages,

```
  \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
```

I just omitted the **[usenames, dvipsnames]** part, and now, it compiles just fine.

Comment: you could more simply have omitted the entire line.

Comment: Note the `\ usenames` option is deprecated, as it has been the default for quite a few years.