# tikz - define color in hex format

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have a color hex string, e.g. ecd9ed, I know I can define it as below:

```
\definecolor{color1bg}{RGB}{236,217,237}
```

But I wish to skip the conversion from hex to decimal. Is it possible to define a color in hex string? Maybe something like below:

```
\definecolor{color1bg}{RGB}{#ecd9ed}
```

Comment: Try `\definecolor{color1bg}{HTML}{ECD9ED}` ... Also, this is an `xcolor` command and possibly tikz is loading it but it is not its job this command...

Comment: @koleygr can you add your comment as an answer so the question can be closed?

Comment: done @jessexknight ... Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

`\definecolor{color1bg}{HTML}{ECD9ED}` is the way to define colors with HTML definition.

You need the package `xcolor` of course.

Comment: Thanks! Just also confirming that tikz [does indeed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488) load `xcolor` already, as you mentioned above.