# How can I make this type of section heading? (Section font is Montserrat)

Tags: macros, formatting, color

I want to have this type of section heading for my book.... Any suggestions how it can be achieved....

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class, you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to add the rule and use `\addtokomafont` to change the color. To remove the `chapter` counter from the section number, you can use `\counterwithout` and `\counterwithin*` (if the `section` counter should still depend on the `chapter` counter).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{montserrat}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{section}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}% Original code from scrbook.cls
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{% For sections only
    \par\nobreak
    \rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{DodgerBlue}\nobreak}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\section{Second section}
\blindtext
\section{Third section}
\blindtext
\section{Fourth section}
\blindtext
\section{Photodiode}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: example section]

If you additionally want to change the space between the section number and the title text, you can redefine `\sectionmarkformat`. The original definition (from the KOMA-Script manual, Section 3.16) is:

```
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\enskip}
```

To, e.g., increase the space from half a quad to a full quad you could use

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\quad}
```

Alternatively you can use every horizontal space you want, e.g., `\qquad`, `\hspace{2em}`, `\hspace{1in}`. To start the title text always at the same place, you can use a `\makebox`, e.g.,

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[2in][l]{\thesection\autodot\hfill}}
```

You can even move the number into the left margin, as explained in an example in the KOMA-Script manual.

If you are not using a KOMA-Script class see the manual of the used class for information about similar features. If the class does not provide features to configure the section headings, you may use a package like `titlesec`. However, I'm almost always using KOMA-Script classes, so I cannot tell you, how the configuration has to be done in this case.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. It's looking great.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I increase spacing between 5 and photodiode. Also when i try with long document "xcolor" package is showing error

Comment: @Mehraj-ud-Din These are two new questions. Usually you should ask a new question. However, I've added an answer to the first one into my answer. But I cannot answer the second one, because I even do not now the error. If it is an *option clash*, see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz If this does not help, please ask a new question with a minimal working example, that reproduces the error message. And please do not forget to specify the exact error message.