# Help with chapter format in koma script \frontmatter \mainmatter

Tags: koma-script, chapters

I am trying to customize the chapter formats in different matter of the document.
How can I obtain a blue bar under the chapter headers from the frontmatter ? This is the best I obtained so far...

Note: If you don't have arial font, replace by anything so you can run the example.

```latex
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    11pt,
    cleardoublepage=empty,
    numbers=noenddot,
    titlepage,
    toc=bibliography,
    chapterprefix=true,
    headings=chapterprefix,
    toc=index,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{textcase}
 
% fonts
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily\AdobeCaslonPro{Adobe Caslon Pro}
%\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstBT{ZapfHumnst BT}
%\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstDmBT{ZapfHumnst Dm BT}
%\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstUltBT{ZapfHumnst Ult BT}
\newfontfamily\AdobeCaslonPro{arial}
\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstBT{arial}
\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstDmBT{arial}
\newfontfamily\ZapfHumnstUltBT{arial}

% colors
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,141,198}
\definecolor{mediumbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,171,238}
\definecolor{lightbluejebrack}{RGB}{114,214,247}


\newcommand{\titleprefixfontsize}{\fontsize{30}{30}}
\newcommand{\titlefontsize}{\fontsize{20}{20}}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\titlesubbar}{{\color{lightbluejebrack} \rule[.4\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2mm}}}

%% This is for the spacing around chapter (above and under)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\matter@switch{}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\matter@switch}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\titleprefixfontsize \normalfont \bfseries \ZapfHumnstDmBT \MakeTextUppercase}%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\titlefontsize \AdobeCaslonPro \bfseries}%
  \setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\titleprefixfontsize \normalfont \bfseries \ZapfHumnstDmBT 
  \MakeTextUppercase}
  % Add a blue line under "CHAPTER"  
  \renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\nobreak\vspace{-.15cm}%
  \titlesubbar\par\nobreak%%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\kern-\dp\strutbox}
  #3%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could do this similar to [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671963/277964), redefining `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` instead of `\sectionlinesformat`. Note, that the commands have a different number of arguments. For another example see also: “[How to put a horizontal line above and below chapter headings](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_ChapterWithLines/)” in the KOMA-Script Wiki.

Comment: Just a note: If the font does not matter, it would be better to remove all font code or replace it by a free font available in TeX Live and MiKTeX independent from the OS. It is always a bit demotivating when the first LaTeX run ends in an avoidable error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `\titlesubbar` also to a redefined `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` inside the `\frontmatter` addon:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    11pt,
    cleardoublepage=empty,
    numbers=noenddot,
    titlepage,
    toc=bibliography,
    chapterprefix=true,
    headings=chapterprefix,
    toc=index,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{textcase}
 
% colors
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,141,198}
\definecolor{mediumbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,171,238}
\definecolor{lightbluejebrack}{RGB}{114,214,247}


\newcommand{\titleprefixfontsize}{\fontsize{30}{30}}
\newcommand{\titlefontsize}{\fontsize{20}{20}}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlesubbar}{{\color{lightbluejebrack} \rule[.4\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2mm}}}

%% This is for the spacing around chapter (above and under)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\matter@switch{}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\matter@switch}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\titleprefixfontsize \normalfont \bfseries \MakeTextUppercase}%
  \renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    {#2#3}% original definition
    \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{\vskip-\dp\strutbox\titlesubbar\par\nobreak}{}% added
  }
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\titlefontsize \bfseries}%
  \setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\titleprefixfontsize \normalfont \bfseries  
  \MakeTextUppercase}
  % Add a blue line under "CHAPTER"  
  \renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\nobreak\vspace{-.15cm}%
  \titlesubbar\par\nobreak%%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\kern-\dp\strutbox}
  #3%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: not numbered chapter with line]

Note: I've removed the fonts to make the example compile independent from OS and installed fonts and independent from the TeX engine.

Note also: Because `\MakeTextUppercase` is not a font command, using in the second argument of `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` it outside the specification and therefore dangerous. IMHO it would be better to move it into the redefinition of `\chapterlineswidthprefixformat`:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    11pt,
    cleardoublepage=empty,
    numbers=noenddot,
    titlepage,
    toc=bibliography,
    chapterprefix=true,
    headings=chapterprefix,
    toc=index,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{textcase}
 
% colors
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,141,198}
\definecolor{mediumbluejebrack}{RGB}{0,171,238}
\definecolor{lightbluejebrack}{RGB}{114,214,247}


\newcommand{\titleprefixfontsize}{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\titlefontsize}{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlesubbar}{{\color{lightbluejebrack} \rule[.4\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2mm}}}

%% This is for the spacing around chapter (above and under)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\matter@switch{}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\matter@switch}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\titleprefixfontsize \normalfont \bfseries}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{\normalfont\itshape}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\usekomafont{chapterprefix}}%
}
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\matter@switch{}%
  }%
  \setkomafont{chapter}{\titlefontsize \bfseries}%
}

% Add a blue line under "CHAPTER" resp. under the title
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \MakeTextUppercase{#2}%
  \if@mainmatter
    \nobreak% shouldn't be needed here
    \vspace{-.15cm}%
    \titlesubbar\par
    \nobreak% shouldn't be needed here
    #3%
  \else
    \MakeTextUppercase{#3}%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{\vskip-\dp\strutbox\titlesubbar\par\nobreak}{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

The notes about `\nobreak` are there, because `\chapter` should always start a new page and therefore inside a chapter title a page break should never happen. If is would be needed, you are in trouble with and without the `\nobreak`. ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for !!! Thanks a lot :) And your explanations are very clear !